# Custom Currency symbol and decimal places using decimal.ToString("C") and CultureInfo

Tags: c#, decimal, currency

I have a problem with `decimal.ToString("C")` override.
Basically what I wants to do is as follows:

```
CultureInfo usCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = usCulture;

NumberFormatInfo LocalFormat = (NumberFormatInfo)NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone();
LocalFormat.CurrencySymbol = "RM";
```

I wants to make above code a function (override ToString("C")) whereby when the following code get executed:

```
decimal paid = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["TotalPaids"]);
lblPaids.Text = paid.ToString("C");
```

The results would be RM4,900.00 instead of $4,900.00

How do I create an override for `decimal.ToString("C")` that would solve my problem

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any chance you could edit the title to be more descriptive?  "decimal.ToString("C")" doesn't indicate what you are asking so when it shows up in Google it's unclear what the question is about.

Comment: @SteveHiner how about the title now?

Comment: @Korayem: Much better. :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To get a format like RM 11,123,456.00 you also need to set the following properties

```
CurrentCulture modified = new CultureInfo(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = modified;
var numberFormat = modified.NumberFormat;
numberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "RM";
numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 2;
numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
numberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ",";
```

If you do that at application startup then that should make ms-MY format like en-US but with the RM currency symbol every time you call the `ToString("C")` method.

Comment: Thanks Mike. My CultureInfo is ms-MY. But for the purpose of displaying currency value, I need to use en-US because it display correctly. E.g ms-MY = R11.747.435 and en-US = RM11,747,435.00 .
Is there any other way, how about the ToString("C") method overriding. Could you please help me with that.

Comment: @Agamand The True - You can either always call `ToString("C", LocalFormat)` Or change some of the other properties on the current cultures NumberFormatInfo. It seems that you just want to change the separator and number of decimal places. I'll edit the answer to include that.

Comment: Thanks Mike, This is perfect. But when I put this in Global.asax, Application_Start method. I get this error 
'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' does not contain a definition for 'NumberFormatInfo' and no extension method 'NumberFormatInfo' accepting a first argument of type 
'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
I've already imported System.Globalization. How can I solve this....

Comment: @Agamand The True - Sorry about that. The property on `CultureInfo` is called `NumberFormat` its type is `NumberFormatInfo`. My mistake. I fixed the code in the answer.

Comment: When I run the given code, I get another error saying Instance is read-only. I don't understand why, because NumberFormatInfo has getter and setter. Could you please explain a bit more..

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question correctly what you want is to replace the $ with RM. If so, you need to pass the custom format...

```
lblPaids.Text = paid.ToString("C", LocalFormat);
```

Comment: Tq for the answer, but the local CultureInfo is (ms-MY).
Since I'm using windows XP the currency sign for this culture is R and not RM which is the correct sign.

Comment: Well then you need to change the value you are setting: LocalFormat.CurrencySymbol = "R";

Answer (score 2):

use this format string :

> ```
> #,##0.00 $;#,##0.00'-  $';0 $
> ```

```
decimal paid = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["TotalPaids"]);
lblPaids.Text = paid.ToString("#,##0.00 $;#,##0.00'-  $';0 $");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Double.ToString Method (String, IFormatProvider) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8ztz0sa(v=vs.110).aspx

```
double amount = 1234.95;

amount.ToString("C") // whatever the executing computer thinks is the right fomat

amount.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-ie"))    //  €1,234.95
amount.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-es"))    //  1.234,95 € 
amount.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB"))    //  £1,234.95 

amount.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-au"))    //  $1,234.95
amount.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"))    //  $1,234.95
amount.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-ca"))    //  $1,234.95
```

Answer (score -1):

```
lblPaids.Text = paid.ToString("C",usCulture.Name);
```

Or

```
lblPaids.Text = paid.ToString("C",LocalFormat.Name);
```

must Work