# Using NumberFormat property in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tostring, .net-core, asp.net-core-localization

[The localization system has changed quite a bit in ASP.NET Core](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/setting-thread-culture-aspnet5). The `CurrentCulture` is no longer available in the current thread.

I'm trying to set `NumberFormat` property of `CurrentCulture` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316663/5173926), in order to customize the format for displaying money but obviously it's no longer possible that way. So how does one set the `NumberFormat` property for `CurrentCulture`?

The code that used to work for this before asp.net core:

```
CurrentCulture modified = new CultureInfo(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = modified;
var numberFormat = modified.NumberFormat;
numberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "RM";
numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 2;
numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
numberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ",";
```

Then for example somewhere in my code I want to do:

```
string fMoney;
fMoney = money.ToString("C");
return fMoney;
```

and expect the `numberFormat` settings to be applied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `UseRequestLocalization` to the `Configure()` method in *Startup.cs*:

```cs
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestCulture(new CultureInfo("es")));
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(HtmlEncoder.Default.HtmlEncode(1000.5f.ToString("C")));
        });
    }
```

Result:

> 1.000,50 €

Also, more to the point of the original question:

```cs
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

        var modified = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture.DisplayName);
        modified.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "RM";
        modified.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 2;
        modified.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
        modified.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ",";

        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestCulture(modified));
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(HtmlEncoder.Default.HtmlEncode(1000.5f.ToString("C")));
        });
    }
```

Result:

> RM1,000.50

Comment: It seems the signature of `app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestCulture(modified));` has changed. It now wants a `RequestLocalizationOptions` object.